# Angular SSR with Nrwl/Nx - external library calls document.getElementById

Tags: angular, plotly, server-side-rendering, angular-universal

In a current project I am implementing Angular server side rendering on a Nrwl/Nx workspace. I went strictly after these [guidelines](https://blog.nrwl.io/nx-workspace-schematics-server-side-rendering-ssr-with-angular-universal-afc04ead55) from Nrwl. Everything works fine until running the node application. The project contains an external library called Plotly.js which unfortunately utilizes the `document`. It throws the following error

```
/Users/PATHTOPROJECT/node_modules/plotly.js/dist/plotly.js:105975
    var style = document.getElementById(id);
                ^
ReferenceError: document is not defined
```

Plotly.js is imported in the lazy-loaded NgModule

```js
import * as PlotlyJS from 'plotly.js/dist/plotly.js';
import { PlotlyModule } from 'angular-plotly.js';
PlotlyModule.plotlyjs = PlotlyJS;
```

Of course in SSR the `document` is not available. Plotly.js is only used in a lazy loaded route. I've tried to guard this route to be only available on  `isPlatformBrowser` but that does not solve the problem. Maybe there is the possibility to add a "fake" `document` or something like that?

Do you have any ideas? Thanks and cheers!

Comment: Where are you including/using plotly.js?

Comment: Did you try `ngAfterViewInit()` ?

Answer (score 0):

Most important you need is: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/9b9116c79d626b6356f3dfe0d48c9d990ac412a2/packages/platform-browser/src/browser.ts#L100

But im to low experienced to show you how to make custom `BrowserModule.withServerTransition()` You can read documentation and try by your self.

Here you have sollution how to import librarys to component using `ngAfterViewInit()`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51150552/6310260

Because you want to manipulate styles. This is one of a way it will work on SSR:

**template:**

```html
<div [ngStyle]="setStyle(item.img)"></div>
```

**component.ts**

```js
setStyle(imgUrl: string) {
    return {
      'background-image': `url('${imgUrl}')`,
      'background-position': 'center',
      'background-repeat': 'no-repeat',
      'background-size': 'cover'
    }
  }
```

**Second one:** try "lifecycle-hook" `ngAfterViewInit()`.